# $setValidity on child element that will eventually exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-ngmodel

I'm probably going about this the wrong way but I have a control that allows multiple files to be dropped on it for the sake of uploading them. With each file, it's file size is displayed and a text box is shown to allow entry of a description of the file. As it's multiple files, one file on the dropzone is represented by its name, size and description text box (and any associated errors).

When a file is dropped on the dropzone, I check it's file size and if it exceeds the stated maximum then the `$setValidity` method is called with arguments `'maxFileSize'` and false. This sets the validity of the dropzone - it exists so that's OK. I also want to set the validity of the file (represented by the controls).

Here is the [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/aloixY5xnaOSLP8NSzrM?p=preview).

In the controller for the directive, I listen for the `filesSelected` event, body is shown here:

```
$scope.$on('filesSelected', function(event, args) {
    var filesValid = true, files = args.files;
    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < files.length; cnt++) {
        var fileValid = files[cnt].size <= $scope.maxFileSize;
        if (!fileValid) {
            filesValid = false;
        }
        $scope.form[files[cnt].name].$setValidity('maxFileSize', fileValid);
    }
    ngModel.$setValidity('maxFileSize', filesValid);
});
```

Basically, the line:

```
$scope.form[files[cnt].name].$setValidity('maxFileSize', fileValid);
```

Expects the control group for the file to exist when, because it's still dealing with the drop event, does not yet exist.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could tackle this?

Comment: `form[files[cnt].name]` is the input field for the description. Also as soon as its content is changed its validity is changed as well. So `$scope.form[files[cnt].name].$setValidity('maxFileSize', fileValid);` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You are correct, I guess that is another problem I will face, but for just now, suppose I had tied it to another hidden field that can't be changed, how would I do that?

Comment: You can wrap the call into a [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout). A delay shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, there must be some "angular way" to do it, I think I have to wait for the current digest cycle to complete (???) but I don't know how I can tap into that to trigger the $setValidity call once it's complete.